# Can a Mac Mini have 3 external monitors connected to it?

Tags: display, mac-mini

Thinking of getting a mac mini for work.

Can I connect three monitors to it? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a mac mini can have multiple monitors connected to it. There are now very good USB to Video solutions on the market that will correct this limitation.

**Steps:**

- Choose a good Mac compatible USB to DVI or USB to VGA adapter. There
  are many available from different manufacturers. Look for adapters
  that contain the DisplayLink chip as these are Intel-Mac compatible.
- Make sure you've downloaded the latest DisplayLink Mac Drivers, like
  these: http://sewelldirect.com/Drivers/DisplayLink-OSx-1.1.zip
- Install the drivers through the guided setup by first selecting the
  image file (.dmg) and opening it, accept the license agreement,
  select which drive to install the driver on (Macintosh HD), press the
  install button, and restart your computer.
- Plug your USB to Video adapter into your computer's USB port and
  attach your monitor's cable to the adapter. You can do this while
  your computer is on and it will recognize the device in the same way
  it recognizes most plug-n-play devices.
- Once your computer recognizes the adapter, it should automatically
  extend your desktop. If you prefer that it mirror the original
  monitor instead, or if you want to change any of the resolution
  settings, go to the Systems Preferences area and select "Displays".

*When setting up multiple monitors choosing two of the same size is recommended.*

[Source.](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Multiple-Monitors-to-a-Mac-Mini)

Comment: Note that displaylink is slower than using the built-in graphics card (because the bandwidth is smaller over USB).  Modern USB-C may carry a video signal too, but that is also driven by the graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

I'd depending on your output resolution requirement I'd use a Triplehead2Go DP Edition to take a single output and split it into two (or three).

The obvious issue the th2g is that it not possible to to output higher than 4080 x 768 (3 x 1360 x 768). The device can do 5760 x 1080 (3 x 1920 x 1080) but the OS cannot choose the correct output settings.

You can also put dualhead2Go on the displayport output and then use the HDMI for the third monitor, this way each output on the dualHead can output up to 1920x1200 @ 50 or 60Hz.